# Enabling debug mode on Android n moto e4 plus

Tags: android, debugging, android-7.0-nougat

I tried to enable the debug mode on my new moto e4 plus but getting problem in doing so.
Debugger mode has been enabled via build version and the usb debug is also enabled. 
After hitting the first break point the app immediately stops with message:
"App has stopped". open again.

Error Image attached.[image]

```
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] "ParseCommandCache.runLoop()" prio=5 tid=25 Waiting
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e580d0 self=0x9ce3b500
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | sysTid=5485 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x81383920
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | state=S schedstat=( 1116999 126308 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | stack=0x81281000-0x81283000 stackSize=1038KB
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | held mutexes=
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #00 pc 00017544  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #01 pc 000b7309  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #02 pc 002a2d47  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+534)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #03 pc 002a4593  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+258)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #04 pc 002b2daf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL11Object_waitEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+32)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #05 pc 00000557  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+74)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - waiting on <0x04132f19> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.runLoop(ParseCommandCache.java:664)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - locked <0x04132f19> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.access$000(ParseCommandCache.java:40)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache$2.run(ParseCommandCache.java:188)
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] "pool-8-thread-3" prio=5 tid=26 TimedWaiting
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e58550 self=0x9ce3c900
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | sysTid=5490 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x8127e920
10-21 11:22:27.876 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | state=S schedstat=( 5055154 58154 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | stack=0x8117c000-0x8117e000 stackSize=1038KB
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | held mutexes=
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #00 pc 00017548  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #01 pc 000b7731  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadExi+108)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #02 pc 002a2d59  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+552)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #03 pc 002a4593  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+258)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #04 pc 002b2ddb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Object_waitJIEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+36)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #05 pc 00000655  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+96)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - waiting on <0x0adadbde> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - locked <0x0adadbde> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] "pool-8-thread-4" prio=5 tid=27 TimedWaiting
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e585e0 self=0x9b6e6200
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | sysTid=5496 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x81179920
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | state=S schedstat=( 45673845 15807233 29 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | stack=0x81077000-0x81079000 stackSize=1038KB
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | held mutexes=
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #00 pc 00017548  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #01 pc 000b7731  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadExi+108)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #02 pc 002a2d59  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+552)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #03 pc 002a4593  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+258)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #04 pc 002b2ddb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Object_waitJIEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+36)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #05 pc 00000655  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+96)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - waiting on <0x09e171bf> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - locked <0x09e171bf> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] "pool-8-thread-5" prio=5 tid=28 TimedWaiting
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e7dca0 self=0x9b6e3a00
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | sysTid=5510 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x81074920
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | state=S schedstat=( 67703999 23451386 17 ) utm=6 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | stack=0x80f72000-0x80f74000 stackSize=1038KB
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   | held mutexes=
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #00 pc 00017548  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #01 pc 000b7731  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadExi+108)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #02 pc 002a2d59  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+552)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #03 pc 002a4593  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+258)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #04 pc 002b2ddb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Object_waitJIEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+36)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   native: #05 pc 00000655  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+96)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - waiting on <0x0e5fd08c> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   - locked <0x0e5fd08c> (a java.lang.Object)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-21 11:22:27.877 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-21 11:22:27.878 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.878 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:460] 
10-21 11:22:27.879 5128-5136/com.tapontips.tapon A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5136 (JDWP)
10-21 11:22:28.531 298-610/? E/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_3gpp_status_ind, 1617) [RDS-E][RU][EVENT_RU_DM_3GPP_STATUS_IND] Invalid u43gpp_status:0x8
10-21 11:22:28.944 924-1504/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
10-21 11:22:28.945 924-1504/? E/Sensors: go to batchsensor(0
```

Comment: post the error log

Comment: I could not find the error in the log cat. i just appended the last lines of the logcat as there is limit in attaching the log.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to debug the application on android N with android studio 2.3
When i upgraded the android studio to 3.0 things started working well.